# Is it possible to put wax or PE or any kind of insoluble coating on soluble material (e.g. edible film)?

Tags: solubility

I'm working on a project to make a cup that can holds hot/cold water inside but can be dissolved from the outside. I'm just wondering if that would be possible scientifically??

Comment: Try it. Make a sugar-glass container and line it with something insoluble.